# Mathematica 2d list select

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica, list-manipulation

I have a 2D list - 128 rows of 128 elements (this data is setup for ContourPlot). I want to quickly select the items from the groups that are smaller than some epsilon.

For instance, using a 3x3 list: p = {{1,2,3},{4,5,1},{7,8,2}}

I'd like to select out the elements that are, say, < 3.

{{1,2},{1},{2}}

I know Select[Flatten[p],# < 3&] would work, but I'll lose the list structure.

Any ideas? (Do I have to use a for loop?)

Rick

Comment: `Select[#, #<3& ]& /@ p` ? (with apologies about the nested `Function`s, which does work, but it's quite unreadable)

Answer (score 2):

mThank you for providing a specific concrete example.

```
In[1]:= p = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1}, {7, 8, 2}};
In[2]:= q = p //. {h___, m_ /; m > 2, t___} -> {h, t}

Out[2]= {{1, 2}, {1}, {2}}
```

Or in english, make q equal to p after you have repeatedly replaced every list that has a (possibly empty) beginning and any element greater than 2 and a (possibly empty) end with the list that is just the beginning and the end. I would have written head and tail, but those already have meanings in Mathematica that might have been confusing.